# Django; requirement dependencies on sets of fields

Tags: python, django

How could I add rules to a Django Model making certain fields that aren't required by default, required if another field is set. Or even the other way around

Let's say I have this Model:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 75)
    cant_be_sold = models.BooleanField()
    flat_price = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True, default = None, validators = [MinValueValidator(0)])
    defense = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True, default = None, validators = [MinValueValidator(0)])
    required_classes = models.ManyToManyField('otherappname.Class', related_name = 'Requires_Classes', blank = True, null = True, default = None)
```

Let's say there can be 2 situations here;

1. I mark `cant_be_sold` as `True`; now flat_price can only be `None` (`NULL`)
2. I fill in `defense`; now it IS required to select one or more `required_classes`

I wonder what the nice way to do this in Django is. Would help me a bunch to prevent wrongfully entries, as my Item model has over 70 property fields, due to the great extend of Item Variances in my system.

Comment: are you using django form?

Comment: @HieuNguyen No not yet, I'm trying to see how much logic I can put in my Models before starting on using customized Django Admin Forms. I can debug a lot now as I have tons of test data to insert :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a [`clean`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) method for your model. In it, you can change field values, and raise validation errors. The following example should get you started.

```
def clean(self):
    if self.cant_be_sold and self.flat_price is not None:
        raise ValidationError("flat_price must be None when cant_be_sold is True")
```

Comment: Thanks Alasdair. Doesn't look that hard :) Small question, as I can't start working until tonight. Can I stack the ValidationErrors to all show at once or is there always only one showing? In other words, collect them all before quitting execution

Comment: When you raise the exception you exit the clean function. If you want to display multiple errors at once, you could collect them in a list then raise the exception at the end. Model forms do provide a way to [assign multiple errors to fields at once](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Comment: Fair enough :) Can I mark the fields (the default red message above it) from the Model too or would I need Forms from that point?

Comment: There is a ticket [16986](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16986) to allow Model.clean to report errors on individual fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Seems a tad old but I can work with this, as it's mostly meant for the Admin side. The front end won't get much forms so I could manual check those. Thanks again!